# To calculate login hours on hourly level, when you have login and logout timestamp in mysql or tableau

Tags: mysql, sql, date, tableau-api, recursive-query

I have login and logout time. Need to calculate login hours on hourly level (hour wise)

Sample Input

```
Login At "2020-03-01 00:11:23" 
Logout AT "2020-03-02 00:01:00"
```

Sample Output

```
Date               Hour            Login Hours
2020-03-01          0                  0.82
2020-03-01          1                   1
2020-03-01          2                   1
2020-03-01          3                   1
2020-03-01          4                   1
2020-03-01          5                   1
2020-03-01          6                   1
2020-03-01          7                   1
2020-03-01          8                   1
2020-03-01          9                   1
2020-03-01          10                  1
2020-03-01          11                  1
2020-03-01          12                  1
2020-03-01          13                  1
2020-03-01          14                  1
2020-03-01          15                  1
2020-03-01          16                  1
2020-03-01          17                  1
2020-03-01          18                  1
2020-03-01          19                  1
2020-03-01          20                  1
2020-03-01          21                  1
2020-03-01          22                  1
2020-03-01          23                  1
2020-03-02          0                   0.02
```

Comment: In your sample input, are the two values stored in the same row, or in different rows?

Comment: same row but different columns login and logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a recursive query. The logic is to iterate over each entire hour within the date range, and compute the `login_hours` at every step, using `timestampdiff()`:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        date_format(login_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') login_at,
        logout_at,
        timestampdiff(
            second,
            login_at,
            date_format(login_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') + interval 1 hour
        ) / 60 / 60 login_hours
    from mytable
    union all
    select 
        login_at + interval 1 hour,
        logout_at,
        timestampdiff(
            second,
            login_at + interval 1 hour,
            least(logout_at, login_at + interval 2 hour)
        ) / 60 / 60
    from cte
    where login_at + interval 1 hour < logout_at
)
select date(login_at) date, hour(login_at) hour, round(login_hours, 2) login_hours
from cte
order by login_at
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76491d6b9e91e70fe52e364915b0a2ce)**:

Original dataset:

```
login_at            | logout_at          
:------------------ | :------------------
2020-03-01 00:11:23 | 2020-03-02 00:01:00
```

Query results:

```
date       | hour | login_hours
:--------- | ---: | ----------:
2020-03-01 |    0 |        0.81
2020-03-01 |    1 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    2 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    3 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    4 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    5 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    6 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    7 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    8 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |    9 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   10 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   11 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   12 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   13 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   14 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   15 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   16 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   17 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   18 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   19 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   20 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   21 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   22 |        1.00
2020-03-01 |   23 |        1.00
2020-03-02 |    0 |        0.02
```